# How To make Tablet Compatibility of Android App?

Tags: android

I have developed Mobile Application which is published on Google play. Now client requires the app to be Compatible with Tablet Devices. I know that all different drawable folders are used for different density devices.

I have started with Tablet Designs and completed all of them by taking another layout folder naming layout-large.

Now My Question is Should I need to design the Tablet Screen separately for 7",9" and 10" screens? or for any tablet device the screen designs saved in layout-large folder will be used for tablets.

I am not sure of the above thing and I have even took another folder with layout-sw720dp name and done designations for 9" tablet. here I have used some different images as we have more space. As I have only 7" tablet to test it and when tested seeing all screens fine which are used from layout-large folder. When I sent my apk file to client, It is known that client is also able to see only layout-large folder screens.

I searched a lot on this all I find is to have separate layout but nothing I found about designing screens suitable for all tablets or individually. Reading android tutorial, i found we should use specifiers sw600dp, sw720dp. this mean both should be there or any one enough is not understood.

I am very sorry for my english and this is very first time I am doing Tablet Compatibility of a mobile app. Please help in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: some 7" devices uses large folder layouts and some uses sw600dp, it depends on the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I need to design the Tablet Screen separately for 7",9" and 10" screens?

Hopefully not, but that is impossible to answer in the abstract.

> or for any tablet device the screen designs saved in layout-large folder will be used for tablets.

Yes. If you do not provide a `res/layout-xlarge/` directory, `-xlarge` devices (e.g., 10" tablets) will use `res/layout-large/`.

> Reading android tutorial, i found we should use specifiers sw600dp, sw720dp. this mean both should be there or any one enough is not understood

You are welcome to use those if you wish. Note that they only work on Android 3.2 and higher.

Comment: I am very thankful for your answer and now my confusion was clear. I just want one more clarification. while googling on the same, I found that large,xlarge specifiers are deprecated. Is it true? if so then I can use sw600dp, sw700dp. But problem is my app build sdk is 2.1, and I read sw600dp, sw700dp will not work for pre-honeycomb devices. How Can I get some solution on this.

Comment: @NR2812: "Deprecated" in Android means "we have another solution that we think you should consider". In the case of `-large` and kin, they were deprecated in Android 3.2. However, their replacements were only added in Android 3.2. The "deprecated" original buckets are your only choice for devices running Android 3.1 and below, and those buckets work perfectly fine on Android 3.2 and higher as well. I am recommending that people stick with the older buckets until Android 2.x has faded away, unless you have specific needs for the new `-swNNNdp` system.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is compatible for all android Phone Devices and Tablets as well.
Here is the solution for the same

```
public String getScreenResolution()
    {
    int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
     switch(screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE:
    deviceResolutionString="tablet";
    // This will returns tablet , you can start your tablet activity from here 
     break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
    deviceResolutionString="tablet";
    // This will returns tablet , you can start your tablet activity from here 
    break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
    deviceResolutionString="device";
    // This will returns Phone , you can start your phone activity from here 
    break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
    deviceResolutionString="device";

    // This will returns Phone , you can start your phone activity from here 
    break;
    default:
    }
    returndeviceResolutionString;
    }
```